# Magento review working out stars out of ten not five

Tags: php, magento, rating

It appears my magento reviews are working out the star ratings out of 10 and not 5. I had 10 radio boxes strangely to begin with. After looking in the database I saw I had many entries in the ratings table. After deleting these extra entries, the user now enters star ratings using radio buttons out of 5. Which is now correct. However the star rating other customers see is being worked out still out of 10. So a star rating of 4/5 is showing as 40% on the stars, when it should be 80%. It is half what it should be. How can I change it so it stops working out the stars out of 10?

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly complex section of Magento, but if you start by poking around `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View` and `Mage_Rating_Block_Entity_Detailed` you should be able to find the code that generates the number that determines summary count. It sounds like it's dividing the review total (out of 100) by 10 (10 stars) rather than 20 (5 stars).  Without seeing your code its difficult to help any further.